how to calculate E[M|G] given event G and random variable M
In my problem, I have two random number generators which each of them has the mean$${\mu}_1$$ and $${\mu}_2$$
also $${X}_s-{\mu}_i$$ for each arm is 1-subgaussian random variable. I defined the below event on random variables generated by this two arms:
$$ G = \left\{ \left| \hat{\mu}_i(2m) - \mu_i \right| \leq \sqrt{\frac{2 \log(n/\delta)}{m}}, \ i = 1, 2, \ m = 1, 2, \ldots, \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor \right\}$$
where $$ \hat{\mu}_i(2m) $$ denotes the empirical mean for arm ( i ) after ( 2m ) rounds, and $$( \mu_i )$$ is the true mean of arm ( i )
and a random variable :
$$M = \min \left\{ 1 \leq m \leq \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor : \left| \hat{\mu}_1(2m) - \hat{\mu}_2(2m) \right| > 2w(m) \right\}
$$
how to calculate
$$E[M|G]$$
or the maximum value that M can have if G occurs?
(actually I am working on the bandit problem (part (b) of question 6.5 from the book bandit algorithms by tor lattimore and csaba) and for finding upper bound of the regret I need to calculate this expectation but I don't know how)
If there is some miss definition comment for me!
